# 1.9 - Custom Search Result Template

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, xml

If I add the following to a category layout update, it successfully replaces the `catalog/product/list` template:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/category/custom_view_list.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

How can I also do this for the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into `catalogsearch.xml` from

`app\design\frontend\YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_THEME\layout\catalogsearch.xml` If this file does not exist in your custom theme then you can check into

`app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalogsearch.xml`

you can see that under `<catalogsearch_result_index>` layout name of `list.phtml` is `search_result_list` so If you want to change this file then you need to use this as block name. For example you can use this in your `local.xml` (this file should present in your custom theme)

File path of `local.xml` is

`app\design\frontend\YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_THEME\layout\local.xml`

If `local.xml` a file does not exist then you can simply create it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/custom_view_list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>   
</layout>
```